# using mysql to match users postcode in database with session user?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to find a way of displaying users who are local to another user on my website that have a matching post code in the database.

So for instance if user 'a' had a postcode of `m3 4jj` and user 'b' had a postcode of `m3 4aj` then mysql query will display those that match and begin with `m3 4` for instance. I am really new to php and mysql and am not sure if I'm heading in the right direction.

So far I've got this:

```
function get_local_users() {
  global $connection;
  $query = "SELECT *
            From ptb_stats, ptb_users
            WHERE ptb_stats.user_id=ptb_users.id
            AND ptb_stats.user_postcode='m3'";
  $local_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
  confirm_query($local_set);
  return $local_set;
}
```

But now I want to make it so that if the logged in user / "._SESSION['user_id']." has their post code as `m4` or `m5` or `m6` then any other user with a matching post code is shown.

I have tried this:

```
function get_local_users() {
  global $connection;
  $query = "SELECT *
            From ptb_stats, ptb_users
            WHERE ptb_stats.user_id=ptb_users.id
            AND ptb_stats.user_postcode=".$_SESSION['user_postcode']."
  $local_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
  confirm_query($local_set);
  return $local_set;
}
```

but it's causing this error:

```
Database query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4
```

My column in my database which stored the postcode is `user_postcode` so in theory I would've thought this would work; is there any reason why it's not?

Comment: `user_postcode` holds the full post code, e.g. `m3 4jj`, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Put the single quotes back in like so...

```
$query = "SELECT *
        From ptb_stats, ptb_users
        WHERE ptb_stats.user_id=ptb_users.id
        AND ptb_stats.user_postcode='".$_SESSION['user_postcode']."'";
```

Comment: ok ive tried that but for some reason this brings up all users except those with the matching postcodes?

Comment: Can you let us know the structure of your tables and supply some sample data?